# Is it possible to alter a asp.net membership user profile directly in the database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have access to the membership database but the profile property values are stored in some cryptic binary format.

Is there any way to decrypt, alter and save these using only SQL or do I need to implement a user management system using .net?

Comment: I'm instantly curious as to *why* you'd want to be able to do that. =)

Comment: To save time. The application only has an account creation form, no way to edit existing accounts.

Comment: Ah. Well, as stated below, I suspect your best bet is to actually bite the bullet and write a simple profile manager.

Comment: @J.Steen  Now that I think about it, isn't there a simple one available out of the box? The Web Site Administration Tool or something similar?

Comment: @AnnL. Yes, though I suspect that only works when you've got a corresponding project open in Visual Studio - not for anything live. If such is the case, here. =) It's opened from Project > ASP.NET Configuration menu item.

Comment: Yep, there is such a tool and I can run it against the live db but unfortunately it doesn't handle profiles, just accounts and roles. :( Thanks anyway, to both of you. I guess I might as well "clean" this quick and dirty tool and actually make a user management form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, using the membership API is your only option.  And this makes sense:  if the membership database was easy to hack, it'd be easily hacked by anybody with the necessary database access.  Such a person shouldn't necessarily have that power within a company.

Comment: You may be right but i don't see how it relates to security. Since I have access to the database I can just copy a profile or password if I want to gain access, I can even create accounts and assign roles. I can also simply write a silly web app to edit profiles, but it's inconvenient. Seems strange that profiles, of all things, are the hardest to change.